# How to avoid listing the some of the files in Document directory in iCloud storage?

Tags: ios, icloud

I develop an app which stores a backup file in Document directory. My backup & restore process is working fine.
My worry is I don't want my backup file listed in the iCloud, i.e, I don't want to list my backup file under

> ```
> Settings -> iCloud -> Manage Storage -> My App
> ```
>
> [image]

I want my backup file hidden like what whatsapp does, Help me out on how to handle it.

[image]

**Note*** Don't consider it as duplicate for excluding backup, I am expecting ways to backup without listing the files in settings as described in the question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28645742/excluding-the-documents-directory-from-icloud-backup ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excluding the Documents Directory from iCloud Backup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28645742/excluding-the-documents-directory-from-icloud-backup)

Comment: The answer which you suggest is for excluding backup, But my question is about not showing the backup data, I hope I should approach by doing something how whatsapp does saving their data. Whereas what I have done is just saved in the documents folder, I hope the solution would be how to achieve it.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri: I hope my response would have showed that this is not duplicate, Please undo the duplicate, else help me out.

Comment: That link has answer to your question, please read the documentation included in that answer. You should not use documents to store if you don't want to list it under icloud

Comment: Ya, read thorough the documentation, but it doesn't have expected answer, I hope you didn't got my question right, As stated in my question I just want to know how to perform backups like whatsapp chat backup which you can't see in your iCloud storage as attached screenshots. If you have got my question right please let me know how I could achieve the similar behaviour. Thank you.